# Error 1148 (42000) using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to load data into a MySQL table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'f.csv' INTO TABLE tableName
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (C1, C2, C3, C4)
            SET cmj = REPLACE(@cmj,',','.');
```

OS : Ubuntu 14.04

MySQL : 5.7

In file my.cnf I have this config:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
[mysql]
local-infile=1
[client]
loose-local-infile=1
local-infile=1
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The
>   used command is not allowed with this MySQL version, query was: LOAD
>   DATA LOCAL INFILE 'f.csv' INTO TABLE tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY
>   ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (C1, C2, C3, C4)

I think the problem is related to new line in MySQL

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

In my file.csv I have two lines (header + values). If I update my request "IGNORE 1 LINES" to "IGNORE 0 LINES" the first line (header) is inserted.

All lines are considered as one line!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

use **--local-infile**  while connecting database.

```
mysql -hhostname -uusername -p --local-infile  test -A
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: mysql -h localhost -uroot -p --local-infile < file.sql not working

Comment: use             LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
or             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: The same problem

Comment: had the same problem using mysqlsh. But connecting first with mysql -hostname ... solves the problem. Then you can run your Load Data command no problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MySQL reference manual v5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html), the error you received can result from `LOCAL` file capability being disabled either on the server or client side.

Running `mysql` with the `--local-infile` option will enable `LOCAL` capability on the client side, but this won't help if it's disabled on the server, where it's controlled by the system variable `local_infile`.  The easiest way to fix this is to reset the system variable during runtime with the `SET` command:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
```

**Note:** In later versions of MySQL you can make the variable change persist over server restarts with the command

```
SET PERSIST local_infile = 1;
```